# Calculating Resistance of Unknown resistor, total current and voltage across each resistor

Tags: voltage, current, series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSw5Yx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit above has total power dissipation of 60 watts. I need to calculate:

**- Resistance of R2**

> Since it is given that total power is 60 watts, and the series circuit
>   has 120v, then we can calculate total resistance to be RT =
>   (120*120)/60 = 240 ohms
>
> We know we currently have a total known resistance of R1 + R3 = 180
>   ohms. So R2 = 240 - 180 = **60 Ohms**

**- Current in the circuit**

> If we calculated resistance of R2 correctly, then we know RT =
>   R1+R2+R3 = 240 ohms
>
> We know voltage gain VT = 120 Volts.
>
> So total current: IT = VT/RT = 120/240 = **0.5 Amps**

**- Voltage across each resistor**

> Voltage across R1 = V1 = (0.5 A) * (80 ohms) = **40 Volts**
>
> Voltage across R2 = V1 = (0.5 A) * (60 ohms) = **30 Volts**
>
> Voltage across R3 = V1 = (0.5 A) * (100 ohms) = **50 Volts**
>
> To check if our answer is correct we total the voltages 40+30+50 =
>   120 Volts which is our total voltage.

Are my answers correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers look correct.

As a cross check, you are given the voltage (120V) and the total power (60W).  From that you can calculate the current directly.

P=EI, so 60W=120V*I.
I therefore has to be .5A, which matches your other results.